# Increase Item functionality in ecommerce using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add the functionality of increasing items in my ecommerce project but when i increase value of one product it increases of all, how can I approach this differently so that it works the way I want it to.(check the stackblitz link for working example).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const products = [
  { id: 1, clothe: 'pant' },
  { id: 2, clothe: 'shirt' },
  { id: 3, clothe: 'coat' },
];

const Cart = () => {
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(0);

  const increaseItem = () => {
    setItemCount(itemCount + 1);
  };
  const decreaseItem = () => {
    setItemCount(itemCount - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <div> {item.clothe} </div>
          <button onClick={() => increaseItem()}>+</button>
          <span>{itemCount}</span>
          <button onClick={() => decreaseItem()}>-</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

[Working Link for example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-naibp3?file=cart.js)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this maintained separate state for each products.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Cart = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    { id: 1, clothe: 'pant', count: 0 },
    { id: 2, clothe: 'shirt', count: 0 },
    { id: 3, clothe: 'coat', count: 0 },
  ]);
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(0);

  const increaseItem = (index, currentCount) => {
    let uProducts = [...products];
    uProducts[index].count = currentCount + 1;
    setProducts(uProducts);
  };
  const decreaseItem = (index, currentCount) => {
    let uProducts = [...products];
    uProducts[index].count = currentCount - 1;
    setProducts(uProducts);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          <div> {item.clothe} </div>
          <button onClick={(e) => increaseItem(index, item.count)}>+</button>
          <span>{item.count}</span>
          <button onClick={(e) => decreaseItem(index, item.count)}>-</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have separated count state of each `product`.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const products = [
  { id: 1, clothe: 'pant' },
  { id: 2, clothe: 'shirt' },
  { id: 3, clothe: 'coat' },
];

const Cart = () => {
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(products.map((item, index) => 0));

  const increaseItem = (index) => {
    const _itemCount = [...itemCount];

    _itemCount[index]++;

    setItemCount(_itemCount);
  };
  const decreaseItem = (index) => {
    const _itemCount = [...itemCount];

    _itemCount[index]--;

    setItemCount(_itemCount);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          <div> {item.clothe} </div>
          <button onClick={() => increaseItem(index)}>+</button>
          <span>{itemCount[index]}</span>
          <button onClick={() => decreaseItem(index)}>-</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-djh39s?file=cart.js)